# JMeter: Using Windows environment variables (e.g. %HOMEPATH%) in user.properties

Tags: jmeter, configuration

I'd like to customize my JMeter installation. I want to change the directory where the CA Certificate of the Test Recorder is stored. The default value for this is ${JMETER_HOME}/bin.
Is it possible to use Windows environment variables like %HOMEPATH% for doing this?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can customize it using [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization), in particular `proxy.cert.directory` so you can override it to point to whatever folder you want either by specifying the desired path in *user.properties* file or pass it via `-J` command-line argument

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: Is there no way to use dynamic values? What am I doing on a multi user system when each user should use its own directory for working? The directory for the Certificate is only an example. In the next step I like to change the user.dir in the file system.properties. I managed to change this, but the path is now static. 
`user.dir=C:/users/id/JMeter`
My goal is to use a dynamic path which include the %HOMEPATH%. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Of course you can make this dynamic, you can set `proxy.cert.directory=%HOMEPATH%` in *user.properties* file and  even if JMeter installation is shared the certificates will be generated in each user's home directory. Of course `%HOMEPATH%` variable needs to be defined and point to an existing folder. You can also consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) for recording, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When I enter `echo %HOMEPATH%` in cmd this results `\Users\<id>`
When I configure the system.properties like this:
`user.dir=C:%HOME_PATH%/JMeter`
I get this info when I start up JMeter:
`2023-10-20 11:13:03,170 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='C:%HOMEPATH%/JMeter'`
So the %HOMEPATH% variable isn't translated...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you feel the difference between `HOMEPATH` and `HOME_PATH`? If not I cannot help you further. In any case it's not a JMeter-related question so I cannot help you further in any case.

Comment: I'm sorry... There was of course a typo in my post. I used `user.dir=C:%HOMEPATH%/JMeter` in system properties.
But as said before, that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I was telling you to use `proxy.cert.directory` in *user.properties*, if someone else told you to amend `user.dir` in *system.properties* - reach out to him and stop spamming here